# Refresh Data on Page without reload, using Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, pug

I am trying to make a real-time app where I post a message that is stored in a database, then that message must be shown on the same page without refreshing the page refreshH. My log says that the connection of my sockets works but after I send the message the page automatically refresh.

this is my controller where I do the work:

```
postPublicacion : function(req,res,next){

        var currentdate = new Date();
        var datetime = currentdate.getFullYear() + "-"
                                + currentdate.getDate() + "-"
                + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + " "
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":"
                + currentdate.getSeconds();

            console.log(datetime);

        var publicacion = {
            id_user : 1,
            publicacion : req.body.post,
            imagen : null,
            fecha_pub : datetime
        };
        var config =require('.././database/config');
        var db = mysql.createConnection(config);
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8081', { 'forceNew': true });
        var message = 'Enviado';
    socket.on('messages', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
        socket.emit('messages', message)
        // conectamos la DB

        db.connect();

        // insertamos los valores enviados desde el formulario
        db.query('INSERT INTO publicaciones SET ?', publicacion, function(err, rows, fields){
            if(err) throw err;
            db.end();
        });
        req.flash('info', 'Publicación realizada correctamente');
        return res.redirect('/users/panel');
    },

    getPublicacion : function (req, res) {
    mc.query('SELECT publicacion FROM publicaciones', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
                db.end();
        return res.send(results);
    });
}
```

This is my other controlller where I reload the data from the database:

```
getUserPanel : function(req,res,next){
        var config =require('.././database/config');
        var db = mysql.createConnection(config);
        var resultado;
        var usuario = req.user;
        console.log(usuario);

        db.query('SELECT * FROM publicaciones', function(err, rows, fields){
            resultado    = rows;
            res.render('users/panel', {
                isAuthenticated : req.isAuthenticated(),
                items: resultado,
                user: usuario
            });
        });
    }
```

This is my template (pug) where I post the data:

```
div(off-canvas='panel-new-card left reveal')
  .post-container
    form(action='http://localhost:3000/users/panel', method='post')
      textarea.autoExpand(rows='3', name='post', data-min-rows='3', placeholder='Type something...', autofocus='')
      |           
      input.post-new-card(type='submit', name='button', value='Post Card')
```

This is my template where i want to refresh the data from the database:

```
div(off-canvas='panel-new-card left reveal')
  .post-container
    form(action='http://localhost:3000/users/panel', method='post')
      textarea.autoExpand(rows='3', name='post', data-min-rows='3', placeholder='Type something...', autofocus='')
      |           
      input.post-new-card(type='submit', name='button', value='Post Card')
```

Answer (score 1):

To refresh the data, you do not need to resubmit the request which you are doing through another HTTP Post submission. You can do two things in this scenario:

1. If the data refreshment time or event is decided by you then you can implement that logic on the server side and simply re-emit the data whenever you want to renew the data on the front end. 
   E.g

   `socket.emit('messages', newMessageHere)`
2. If the data is refreshed by user on the front end, then emit an event on your front end i.e in your pug template, set a function which emits a custom event to the server:

   `socket.emit('refreshData', userIdentifier)`

And then on the server side, listen to the `refreshData` (or any other name that you like) like this:

```
socket.on('refreshData', function(data) {
      // Your refresh data logic here (from second controller)
    // emit the data then 
    socket.emit('messages', refreshedData)      
    });
```